# Flask add resource endpoint for GET method only

Tags: python, post, get, flask-restful

How do i make `Resource` to pass subdomain as an argument only when `GET` method is triggered?

`localhost:5009/my_url/9952` where `get` method should do some stuff based on id (9952 in this case)
and `localhost:5009/my_url` where `post` does not require any id but it accepts json instead.
Currently i have the following code

```
app = Flask(name)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(MyResourceClass, '/my_url/<int:item_id>', endpoint='item_id')
```

#### view.py

```
class MyResourceClass(Resource):

    def get(self, item_id=None):
        if not item_id:
            # item ID was not provided over get method
            return 404
        # Do stuff
        return 200

    def post(self):
        ## Should accept JSON
        ## Does some stuff based on request

    def delete(self):
        ## Deletes the item information
        return 200
```

obviously it requires `item_id` to present in the URL otherwise post request returns `404` error. How do i make `item_id` to be required only for `GET` method ?

Comment: Please also show your resource code and it would great if you make a clear statement in your question that this is about **Flask-RESTful** not just Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
app = Flask(name)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(MyResourceClass, '/my_url/', '/my_url/<int:item_id>', endpoint='item_id')
```

now `GET` and `POST` will trigger regardless of `item_id` definition in the URL, All methods in `view.py` must be adjusted to handle the case where `item_id` is not provided